# LINQ to SQL (NHibernate): OrderBy vs OrderByDescending abstraction

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a generic search method that can search in a number of different ways, both ascending or descending.

Basis:

`IQueryable<MyModel> query = nhSession.Query<MyModel>();`

My question is, can I in any way abstract away the OrderBy vs OrderByDescending call, so I don't have to make this if-branching for every single ordering option I want to support (simplified to a single column, but could be more complex orderings, including ThenBy)?

```
if (orderAscending)
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
else
    query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

Ideally I want something like this (pseudo-code) using delegates, lambda functions or similar, but can't get something to work:

```
var filterFunc = orderAscending ? query.OrderBy : query.OrderByDescending;
query = filterFunc(query, x => x.SomeProperty);
```

or

```
query = query.Order(x => x.SomeProperty, orderAscending);
```

I would prefer not to use QueryOver if possible, since there is a lot ot other code already in place using vanilla LINQ calls. I tried .Reverse() also, but that does not seem to be supported on the NH LINQ provider.

It is not an option to fetch the entire list, and reverse it in memory, as I only need to extract for example the top 100 of tens of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way, by creating my own extension methods that just wraps the others:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class MyQueryableOrderExtensions
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDirection<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending)
        {
            if (ascending)
                return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
            else
                return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }

        public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenByDirection<TSource, TKey>(this    IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending)
        {
            if (ascending)
                return source.ThenBy(keySelector);
            else
                return source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
query = query
    .OrderByDirection(x => x.MyProperty, orderAscending)
    .ThenByDirection(x => x.OtherProperty, false);
```

Comment: Fixed your code and tidied up the formatting a little :)